# reading integers from a file (in C) which including data of a directed graph

Tags: c, file, graph

Suppose I create a file named **graph-file.txt**, which including data of a

directed graph as the following:

```
7
{5, 2, 3}, {1,5}, {}, { }, {3}, { }, { }
```

The first line of the file shows the number of vertices (7 in that case).
The second line describes the neighbours N+(v) for each vertex. For example, from vertex number 1 edges are directed to vertices 5,2 and 3,   and for vertex number 7 no edges are directed to any of the other vertices in that graph.

**I would like to ask what is the way to read from that file the information about the edges (described above), which needed for BFS algorithm ?**

I use the following functions for BFS:

```
#define SIZE 40

struct queue {
    int items[SIZE];
    int front;
    int rear;
};

struct queue* createQueue();
void enqueue(struct queue* q, int);
int dequeue(struct queue* q);
void display(struct queue* q);
int isEmpty(struct queue* q);
void printQueue(struct queue* q);

struct node
{
    int vertex;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* createNode(int);

struct Graph
{
    int numVertices;
    struct node** adjLists;
    int* visited;
};

struct Graph* createGraph(int vertices);
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest);
void printGraph(struct Graph* graph);
void bfs(struct Graph* graph, int startVertex);


void bfs(struct Graph* graph, int startVertex) {

    struct queue* q = createQueue();

    graph->visited[startVertex] = 1;
    enqueue(q, startVertex);

    while(!isEmpty(q)){
        printQueue(q);
        int currentVertex = dequeue(q);
        printf("Visited %d\n", currentVertex);

       struct node* temp = graph->adjLists[currentVertex];

       while(temp) {
            int adjVertex = temp->vertex;

            if(graph->visited[adjVertex] == 0){
                graph->visited[adjVertex] = 1;
                enqueue(q, adjVertex);
            }
            temp = temp->next;
       }
    }
}


struct node* createNode(int v)
{
    struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->vertex = v;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}


struct Graph* createGraph(int vertices)
{
    struct Graph* graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->numVertices = vertices;

    graph->adjLists = malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node*));
    graph->visited = malloc(vertices * sizeof(int));


    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        graph->adjLists[i] = NULL;
        graph->visited[i] = 0;
    }

    return graph;
}

void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest)
{
    // Add edge from src to dest
    struct node* newNode = createNode(dest);
    newNode->next = graph->adjLists[src];
    graph->adjLists[src] = newNode;

    // Add edge from dest to src
    newNode = createNode(src);
    newNode->next = graph->adjLists[dest];
    graph->adjLists[dest] = newNode;
}

struct queue* createQueue() {
    struct queue* q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->front = -1;
    q->rear = -1;
    return q;
}


int isEmpty(struct queue* q) {
    if(q->rear == -1) 
        return 1;
    else 
        return 0;
}

void enqueue(struct queue* q, int value){
    if(q->rear == SIZE-1)
        printf("\nQueue is Full!!");
    else {
        if(q->front == -1)
            q->front = 0;
        q->rear++;
        q->items[q->rear] = value;
    }
}

int dequeue(struct queue* q){
    int item;
    if(isEmpty(q)){
        printf("Queue is empty");
        item = -1;
    }
    else{
        item = q->items[q->front];
        q->front++;
        if(q->front > q->rear){
            printf("Resetting queue");
            q->front = q->rear = -1;
        }
    }
    return item;
}

void printQueue(struct queue *q) {
    int i = q->front;

    if(isEmpty(q)) {
        printf("Queue is empty");
    } else {
        printf("\nQueue contains \n");
        for(i = q->front; i < q->rear + 1; i++) {
                printf("%d ", q->items[i]);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: A good way to do this is with a *recursive descent* parser.  Write a function `getedges` which you can call 7 times.  Write a *lexical analysis* function which returns single characters like `'{'`, `','`,or `'}'`, or ingeters converted from adjacent runs of digit characters.  Inside `getedges`, call your lexer to check that you've seen a `'{'`, then repeatedly call it to get integers and commas, until you find the `'}'`, then return.  When writing such functions to parse text already contained in a string, I find it useful to pass a `char **` pointer down to the `getedges` and lexer functions.

Comment: @SteveSummit Isn't there any simple way to pass the commas and brackets and read only the integers?

Comment: That depends in part on how you want to deal (if you want to try to deal) with malformed inputs.

Comment: Do you have control over the input format, or is it imposed on you?  If you have no interest in the braces and commas, if you'd rather just ignore them, then why not redefine the input format to not include them in the first place?  A simpler and easier-to-parse input format would be one line per node, each line containing whitespace-separated edge numbers for one node.

Comment: @SteveSummit It's imposed on me. Could you please show me how to ignore the braces commas? how to redefine the input format to not include them in the first place?

Comment: @NOA: If you can't change the format, but you can ignore the braces/commas/etc., then you can use the answer I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is valid, as a fun exercise, I tried to come up with the minimal parser required. For x86_64, it compiles down to [less than 40 instructions](https://godbolt.org/g/SMWMLU), using a handful of registers:

```
void edge(int from, int to);

void parse(void)
{
    int v = 0;
    for (;;) {
        const int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF)
            return;

        // Next 'from' vertex?
        if (c == '{') {
            ++v;
            continue;
        }

        // Ignore vertex count
        if (v == 0)
            continue;

        // Found 'to' vertex?
        int w = c - '0';
        if (w < 0 || w > 9)
            continue;

        // Parse 'to' vertex
        for (;;) {
            const int d = getchar() - '0';
            if (d < 0 || d > 9)
                break;
            w = w * 10 + d;
        }

        edge(v, w);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you need to validate the input, then you will need some more states to take care of the commas, closing braces, mismatching number of vertices, out of range vertex numbers, invalid characters, etc.

Comment: This is StackOverflow, not Code Golf. Parsers not verifying their input keeps being one of the primary reasons for security vulnerabilities. I do not think the proliferation of such dangerous practices is appropriate here.

Comment: Also compare the answers here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368509/how-to-review-suggested-edits-that-fix-security-issues/368510

Comment: @HermannDöppes: This answer is not code golf -- it is not written to minimize source code length. Instead, it strives to be a very simple (simplest?) parser. On top of that, OP has noted that input validation is not needed. Finally, security vulnerabilities only matter in some contexts, not all software is exposed to malicious/untrusted input.

Comment: @HermannDöppes: By the way, in this particular case, the code is hardly exploitable -- it does not even require memory in x86 and can be proved to finish in O(n) steps w.r.t. the input (checking for `d == EOF` if needed). The edges themselves could be validated in `edge()` independently.